# How to get pixel dimensions instead of pt?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I received an illustrator file that I'm trying to break up into it's bits. However everything is measured in pt rather than px. Is there a global setting i can change?

Comment: It is perverse to use pixel units in a vector graphics program.

Comment: @jason404: how would you suggest to convert a design from AI to web?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Edit > Preferences > Units

Change to pixels.

Comment: For Mac users:
Illustrator > Preferences > Units

Answer (score 0):

Alternative option: show grid, right clic > pixels