# Change the default unit in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5

Is it possible to change the default unit of measurement in Photoshop from inches to pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [question/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/185928/how-to-get-pixel-dimensions-instead-of-pt) pertains to Illustrator, but it's the same across Adobe products:

[How to get pixel dimensions instead of pt?](https://superuser.com/questions/185928/how-to-get-pixel-dimensions-instead-of-pt)

Answer (score 0):

You can change it via Edit>Preferences>Units & Rulers